# Diff-in-Diff on Stata: reg vs xtreg + interpretation of coefficients

Tags: regression, stata, regression-coefficients, difference-in-difference

I have two questions about Diff-in-Diff (on Stata) I haven't found any clear answer to.

I refer to this example to make things easier: http://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/DID101.pdf
Let's say:
'country' is a region;
'treatment' is the introduction of a policy for social support of the unemployed;
'y' is an aggregate measure for psychological conditions of people living in that region;

As showed in the example, the straightforward method to assess whether the policy (treatment) has had any effect on psychological conditions (y) is:

`reg y time treated did, r`

1.In an example like this, is there any reason to use panel-data methods?
I mean something like:
`xtset country year`

`*random effect*
xtreg y time treated did, r`

`*or fixed effect*
xtreg y time treated did, fe r`

Would these be "correct" procedures in the DiD setting?
If yes, how would you interpret the results of these other procedures wrt the former?

2.I found a lot of guidance on how to interpret coefficients when a causal effect seems to be there. But what if results are different?

I provide another example for which I have  dataset: now the "countries" are 107 (we could say they are provinces); years are fewer: from 1991 to 1995 included; there is a variable x= "unemployment rate" to control for. The rest is similar to the previous example.

I provide the result of

`reg y time treated did x, r`

[image: output]
The coefficient of 'did' is not (even remotely) significant. This means that I cannot establish a causal effect of the treatment on the outcome variable.

However, the constant term and the coefficients of 'time' and 'x' are statistically significant (even at the 1% level), the former two being positive, the latter negative.

Should I interpret these coefficients? How?

Do they suggest anything about the chosen method (Diff-in-Diff)? Is it possible that adding more control variables (which I have not in my dataset) or choosing another method (like matching) would provide any causal relation?

Thanks a lot